# Is it possible to categorize the app list?

Tags: apps, organization

Now with hundreds of apps in my device, it's really a pain to find an app. Sometimes I don't know its name, which makes it difficult to search. Is there a way to group the apps in my device? Somewhat similar to what we have in marketplace is fine.

Comment: If you don't know it's name, how do you intend to find it in the first place? There's some logic not making sense here.

Comment: I can know part of the name, but don´t know the FIRST LETTER. That is enough to not be able to find an app for a while.

Comment: [Unconfirmed news about tile folders](http://wmpoweruser.com/windows-phone-future-leak-or-fan-wish-list/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Games are always grouped in the Games hub and don't appear in the app list. Otherwise, there is no official way to group apps except pinning them to Start. I've seen some people use live tiles/pinned web pages as titles for dividing categories on the Start page, that may be a workaround.

Comment: You can search for apps, though (if you have upgraded your phone to Mango).

Comment: Something like [TileHeader](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/e24b26a7-15c6-4cf8-a141-409cca197ae4) and [TileHeader2](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/88834c96-d2a9-471c-92f4-fca59b06fdbf).

Answer (score 6):

You can use an application such as [New Group*](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/93ad2492-42b1-4a9d-9999-d67ea86f2abe) to simulate groups on your start screen. It is not ideal, but is a reasonable workaround.

[image: New Group*]

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to organize the app list. But you do not need to:

- If you have more than (I think) 40 apps installed, the same organization as in the People Hub kicks in; just tap a highlighted letter to easily jump to that part of the alphabet.
- There is search button in the top left of the app list which searches for partial matches in all app names. It even has an option to search in Marketplace for apps you do not have installed yet, making it easy to find and download new apps right from there. *Warning*: this search button is new in Mango, so upgrade your phone if you do not see it.
- Apps you use a lot, you can always pin to your home screen, which you can organize any which way you like.

Comment: PeSHlr the problem he had was not remembering the name of the app. the jumplist does require you to remember an apps name or at least it's first letter :) Just having good names for apps should also fix this

Comment: I know: that's why I mention the search button that people seem to often miss. Perfect solution to his problem, because it does partial matching.

Comment: Partil matching works but not in the middle of a word. You can't find _handscan_ if you type _scan_. It is possible if the name change to _HandScan_. Because you can find _AccuWeather_ only by _weather_. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use App Folder, sounds like it does what you want it to do.
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/app-folder/7d2e7de3-95e7-4143-8a9d-aedf8c3f901e